# how to Sending drowpDown values ​to the input of the action controller using the select2 library?

Tags: asp.net-core, jquery-select2, model-binding, asp.net-core-6.0

I want to both the previous tags pass in action controller and the new tags that I enter that do not already exist by Select2

I from Automatic tokenization into tags section in library select2
I want to use

But the new tags that I enter are empty in the action entry

I want to use this part:
https://select2.org/tagging

model:

```
 public class CreateArticleCommand : IRequest<CommandResult>
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<TagsVm>?  Tags { get; set; }
}
```

action:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
    {
        IActionResult viewResult = View(new CreateArticleCommand());

        var tags = await _mediator.Send(new GetAllTagsQuery());

        if (tags.Status == ApplicationServiceStatus.Ok)
        {
          
            viewResult = View(new CreateArticleCommand() { Tags = tags.Data });
        }
        return viewResult;
    }
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CreateArticleCommand articleCommand)
    {
        IActionResult viewResult = View(articleCommand);

        var res = await _mediator.Send(articleCommand);
        if (res.Status == ApplicationServiceStatus.Ok)
            viewResult = RedirectToAction(nameof(List));
        return viewResult;
    }
```

view:

```
@model CreateArticleCommand
<select asp-for="Tags" class="js-example-tokenizer form-control" multiple="multiple"
        asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Tags,nameof(TagsVm.Id), nameof(TagsVm.Name)))">
    </select>
```

js:

```
 <script>
    $(".js-example-tokenizer").select2({
        tags: true,
        tokenSeparators: [',', ' ']
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`slect2` can only pass `List<string>` or `List<int>` to action,it cannot be binded to `List<TagsVm>?  Tags`,here is a demo:

```
public class TagsVm
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
 public class CreateArticleCommand : IRequest<CommandResult>
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<TagsVm>?  Tags { get; set; }
    public List<int>  SelectedIds { get; set; }
}
```

view:

```
@model CreateArticleCommand
<select asp-for="SelectedIds" class="js-example-tokenizer form-control" multiple="multiple"
        asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Tags,nameof(TagsVm.Id), nameof(TagsVm.Name)))">
    </select>
```

action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CreateArticleCommand articleCommand)
    {
        //get selected ids from articleCommand.SelectedIds 
        ...
    }
```

Comment: You don't understand what I mean, the values ​​are displayed on the screen, but when I send the values ​​to the action it is empty

Comment: I want both the values ​​that I have loaded from the database to be sent to the action and the values ​​that I add in select2 to be passed to the action.

Comment: Hello,I have updated my answer,`select2` cannot bind data with `List<TagsVm>?  Tags`.